# remove domain reorder username powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a script which will strip the domain and reorder the first/last.
"microsoft\smith, joe" into "joe smith". I can't get the reorder exactly right. This is what I have:

```
$inputcsv = import-csv "C:\Users\tech\Desktop\naming.csv"
$columnget = $($inputcsv.username)

$shortname = $columnget.replace("microsoft\" , " ")
$removecomma = $shortname.replace("," , " ")

foreach ($line in $columnget){$shortname}
foreach ($line in $shortname){$removecomma}
$thestring = foreach ($line in $removecomma){$line.Split(' ')[1..0]} -join ' '
$thenewstring = "$($thestring[1]+$thestring[0])" | export-csv "C:\Users\tech\Desktop\namingoutput.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be doing a lot of extra unnecessary work. How about:

```
Import-Csv "C:\Users\tech\Desktop\naming.csv" | ForEach-Object {
  $_.username -replace '[^\\]+\\([^,]+), (.+)','$2 $1'
} | Out-File "C:\Users\tech\Desktop\namingoutput.txt"
```

This is assuming your input CSV file has a `username` column that contains usernames in the format `domainname\last, first`.

Comment: yes it does. this works really well. i couldn't see how to process all the steps in one. i can see how you did it.

Comment: that's right, there is a username column with domain\last, first.